# Why am I getting an error 404 when adding HTTPS to my website URL?

Tags: https, http-status-code-404

I recently cloned a website from another host, and everything is working fine. I can access the website front end when I visit the URL "mysitename.com" and "http://mysitename.com" in my browser. However if I try "https://mysitename.com" I get "Error 404. The requested URL was not found on this server."

What could be causing this problem? I think I can rule out my SSL certificate being the issue as I am using the same default certificate provided by my host which I have used with no issues on many other sites. I feel like it has something to do with the config file but I don't know what I would have to add/modify. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the question

- You get a error 404 when you try https://mysitename.com/ while http://mysitename.com/ works just fine.
- SSL Part

The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found, 404, Page Not Found, or Server Not Found error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the browser was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. [Read More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) About 404 error here.

Your previous host gave you an ip and issued you an SSL certificate. Now, you probably want to add a second or third website. Well on a shared host 1 dedicated ip is all you can get. You can only have 1 certificate for a dedicated ip address.

You cloned the website from your previous host now but are using the same SSL certificate it provided you with earlier. Should it get the new ip set up for HTTPS encryption as well? No You probably mean a [Unified Communication Certificate](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-ucc/) here

I'm assuming this was all you were looking for. Hope it helps.